# Atributes disapear when converting from tif to netCDF with gdal translate

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, netcdf

I am using python to convert multiple tif files to netCDF. The code is the following:

```
def tif_to_nc(input_name):
   # Convert TIF to netCDF
   inputfile = project+"process/{}.tif".format(input_name)
   outputfile = project+"output/{}.nc".format(input_name)
   ds = gdal.Translate(outputfile, inputfile, format='NetCDF')
```

It works for most files, but it fails for a particular tiff image which cointains just a few attributes, returning just NaN.

The following warning is also shown (for all files), which I think might be related:

```
Warning 1: Recode from UTF-8 to CP_ACP failed with the error: "Invalid argument".
```

Another way to convert from tiff to gdal that might fix this issue is also welcome.

The file I am trying to convert can be found at http://filedropper.com/u4FRM9Ea

Comment: Impossible to answer without test data. If your tiff files are not public create a test file that does not contain confidential contents but is otherwise similar.

Comment: Thanks, I have added a path to download the test file. When I run the code above with it, I get only NaN in my output nc file

Comment: Works for me from the command line (GDAL 3.6dev) `gdal_translate -f NetCDF example_file.tif example_file.nc
Input file size is 90, 85
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.` All the values in the NC file are 10 just like in the source tif.
I do not quite understand what you mean by "attributes" in this context. Is that something specific to NetCDF?

Comment: By attibutes I meant the values assigned as 10 in this example file. After you mentioned it was working, I was able to trace back the error to how I was generating the tif, before converting. It was not closing the file. After adding a line with ```file = None``` it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gdal_translate (or gdal.Translate() in python) was not working because the tiff file was still "open" after I created and edited it with gdal. It works after adding `file_tiff = None` before converting it.